# Simplify Quadratic Vertex Form Equation to Standard Form

Tags: python, quadratic

I wanted to make a function to get a quadratic equation given the vertex and a point. I got all of this right until, I was using sympy to simplify the expression because that's how it gets to standard form, but it gave me an error. Here is my code:

```
from math import sort
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')

def point_cd_vertex_hk(c,d,h,k):
    a = (d - k) / (c - h) ** 2
    equation = a * (x + h) ** 2 + k 
    print(f"Your equation is y = {equation}")

point_cd_vertex_hk(2,4,6,8)
```

And with this I got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/michaeldavid/Desktop/Coding/Python/Standard/quadratic_for_project.py",
>   line 11, in 
>           quad_point_cd_vertex_hk(2,4,6,8)
>         File "/Users/michaeldavid/Desktop/Coding/Python/Standard/quadratic_for_project.py",
>   line 8, in quad_point_cd_vertex_hk
>           equation = a (x + h) ** 2 + k 
>       TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

I have an idea that it might be something with the fact that the "a" value is a floating point number, but I don't know what is really causing the problem.
What does it mean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are typo in this line `equation = a (x + h) ** 2 + k`.  'a' is not a function. May be `a * (x+h)` is what you are looking for

Comment: Ok I fixed the typo and I found out that `equation = expand(a * (x + h) ** 2 + k` seemingly works, but the b value is negative when the correct equation has b as positive. I even tried it with different points and same thing happened. Strange.